# Cant figure out wiring on HVAC and 2 wire oil furnace (to go with a Nest)

Tags: hvac

Trying to figure out this wiring, but not totally sure I have it right, HEAT does not come on.
Nest thermostat with R,W,Y,G,O, unused Blue,Brown,Grey

Oil furnace with R and W direct from thermostat

HVAC outside with Y direct from thermostat

--return from HVAC goes to "C" on transformer

G from thermostat goes to G on transformer

O from thermostat goes to R on transformer

Everything online talks about a controller board that has all the terminals for the TStat to connect to, but I dont have that and thats whats confusing me.

Im thinking I should wire the TStat wires:
R to R on transformer
W to W on transformer
Y to Y on transformer
B to C on transformer
G (leave connected to G on transformer)
O (leave connected to R on transformer)
Jumper R from transformer to R on oil burner
Jumper W from transformer to W on oil burner
Jumper Y from transformer to Y out to the HVAC

In the pic, the brown cable with white and red leads is from the HVAC outside, the Y wire ties to the red lead in the brown cable and comes back as white to the C on transformer
[image: furnace wiring]

[image: Nest]

[image: transformer]

Comment: What was the R and W to the heater connected to?  Did you have separate thermostats for heat and cool before?  Some oil heaters just require a contact closure rather that 24v from the thermostat, so its important to know how it was working before.

Comment: Red and White were just to the thermostat, if I connect them, the furnace fires up

Comment: Why isn’t the blue wire hooked up to the thermostat C?  Also is there a setting on nest that you have to configure if you have a separate Rc and Rh?  Right now if the nest doesn’t know about Rh and just connects Rc to W, the heat won’t work.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the Rh and W don’t have 24v on them so the nest might not switch it properly.  Making this work will probably involve wiring up another relay.

Comment: What make and model is your oil furnace, and can you post a wiring diagram for the furnace as a whole?